# Python multiprocessing start method doesn't run the process

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I'm new to multiprocessing and I'm trying to check that I can run two process simultaneously with the following code :

```
import random, time, multiprocessing as mp

def printer():
    """print function"""
    z = random.randit(0,60)
    for i in range(5):
        print z
        wait = 0.2
        wait += random.randint(1,60)/100
        time.sleep(wait)
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = mp.Process(target=printer)
    p2 = mp.Process(target=printer)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
```

This code does not print anything on the console although I checked that the process are running thanks to the is.alive() method.

However, I can print something using :

```
p1.run()
p2.run()
```

**Question 1 :** Why doesn't the start() method run the process ?

**Question 2 :** While running the code with run() method, why do I get a sequence like

25,25,25,25,25,11,11,11,11,11

instead of something like

25,25,11,25,11,11,11,25,11,25 ?

It seems that the process run one after the other.

I would like to use multiprocessing for using the same function on multiple files to parallelize file conversion.

Comment: Straight off the bat it looks like you have an extra quotation mark on line 4... this means the rest of your code is a string. I would suggest removing the extra quote after """print function""" and re test your code? You are generating a random integer and the printing to console 5 times with the range(5).

Comment: That was a mistake while copying the code, the problem does not come from here :) I generate a random number once, but print it five times with a random delay in order to have a random sequence while running two process at the same time.

Comment: The code looks fine, apart from typo's. Are you sure you have multiple CPU's available on your system?

Comment: @YtsendeBoer I have 4 cores on my laptop. I tried to make it run on another PC with more cores (8+), same result.

Comment: do `sys.stdout.flush()` after each print statement to be sure your output is not lingering in a buffer.  of course you will also need `import sys`.

Comment: @Skaperen, it did not print anything :/ It looks like the process is starting but does not call the printer() function. Does this code run fine on your computer ?

Answer (score 1):

I made the script run by adding

```
from multiprocessing import Process
```

However, I don't have a random sequence of two numbers, the pattern is always A,B,A,B.. If you know how to show that the two process run simultaneously, any ideas are welcome !

Comment: i am facing the same issue. did you get a solution for this?